# What is wrong with the "&" in this CSS?

Tags: css, meteor, jsfiddle

This CSS works in jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/4vqq2a68/1/):

```
.select-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;

    &::after {
        content: "\2193";
        position: absolute;
        right: 5px;
        top: 0;
    }

    select {
        background: transparent;
        border: 0;
        padding: 3px;
    }
}
```

...but trying to run my meteor app after adding it to my .css file, it fails, saying there is a problem with this line:

```
&::after {
```

...specifically, column 5 (the "&")

I pasted it into csslint.net, and it told me the CSS contains two errors. On the line shown above, it says, "*Expected RBRACE*"

The other error is "*Unexpected token '}' at line 19, col 1. }*

That is the last "}" (and last token) of the CSS.

So I added a "}" before the "&" and removed the last "}", but then got another error: "*Unexpected token '&'*."

Why does it run fine in jsfiddle but fail csslint and in Meteor?

Comment: For one thing, it's not CSS. It's SCSS. Furthermore, you would have had to choose SCSS as an option when constructing your fiddle since it defaults to CSS, so it's not something that can be missed.

Comment: That's LESS, not CSS.  You need to compile it.

Comment: I forked an existing one, moving the class from a div to a select, and getting rid of the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is SCSS which is SASS. Convert back to CSS at [sassmeister](http://sassmeister.com/).
You will get something like...

```css
.select-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.select-wrapper::after {
  content: "\2193";
  position: absolute;
  right: 5px;
  top: 0;
}

.select-wrapper select {
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  padding: 3px;
}
```